# state of a C* algebra

Tags: functional-analysis

If $A$ is unitial algebra and if $\omega$ is a state of $A$, then for all $a\in A$ $$|\omega (a)|\leq\omega (\left | a \right |^{2})^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

How can I prove this corollary? I would like to get a hint.

Comment: Are you sure the RHS is not $w(|a|^2)^{1/2}$?

Comment: yes,of course...Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the sesqui-linear form
$$
(a,b) \mapsto w(b^{\ast}a)
$$
The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality gives
$$
|w(b^{\ast}a)| \leq w(b^{\ast}b)^{1/2}w(a^{\ast}a)^{1/2}
$$
So now take $b=1$ (In fact the same is true for non-unital algebras as well, by taking approximate units instead).